# Adding gFlot library to a GWT project fails

Tags: gwt, module, flot

I downloaded gflot for my gwt project. To get to know the library I created a test project called "FlotDemo". I'm using Eclipse and created a plain vanilla gwt project with the help of the project creation wizard (the stuff with the greeting servlet and so on)

This is what I did:

1. Downloaded gflot-3.1.1.jar and copied it into /war/WEB-INF/lib
2. Added in Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries  gflot-jar to the path
3. Added `<inherits name="ca.nanometrics.gflot.GFlot"/>` to my "FlotDemo.gwt.xml"
4. Went to [gFlot example](http://gflot2.appspot.com/#line%3afilename=LineExample&rawSource=false) and copy an pasted it to my EntryPoint class

So after step 4, eclipse strangly cannot resolve the objects from gflot I used in the code. I tried to run the web app anyway in the gwt simulator but it quit with the error message:

```
2013-06-05 17:24:51.212 java[12069:707] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2013-06-05 17:24:51.213 java[12069:707] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Loading modules
   flotdemo.FlotDemo
      Loading inherited module 'flotdemo.FlotDemo'
         Loading inherited module 'ca.nanometrics.gflot.GFlot'
            [ERROR] Unable to find 'ca/nanometrics/gflot/GFlot.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
         [ERROR] Line 11: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:308)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<inherits name="ca.nanometrics.gflot.GFlot"/>` is the old one.

Since 3.0, use `<inherits name='com.googlecode.gflot.GFlot'/>` instead.

See the [example](https://github.com/nmorel/gflot/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/gflot/examples/GFlotExamples.gwt.xml).